# On a property of harmonic functions of stochastic processes

Tags: stochastic-processes, harmonic-functions

I have a question which relates to an argument appearing in this paper [1](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1994-342-02/S0002-9947-1994-1211410-9/S0002-9947-1994-1211410-9.pdf).

Let $D$ be a domain of $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $X=(X_t, P_x)$ be a diffusion process on $D$.

Let $h : D \to [0,\infty]$ be a harmonic function of $X$.

We define $\sigma_{K}=\inf \{t \ge 0 \mid X_t \in K\}$,
 where $K$ is a compact subset of $D$.

Can we obtain the following identity?:
\begin{align*}
E_{x}\left[\int_{0}^{\sigma_K \wedge \tau_D}\exp(-s)h(X_{s})\,ds \right]=h(x)-E_{x}[\exp(- \sigma_K \wedge \tau_D)h(X_{\sigma_K \wedge \tau_D})],
\end{align*}
where $\tau_D=\inf \{t>0 \mid X_t \notin D\}$.

Thank you in advance.

**My attempt**

We assume that $X$ is a absorbing Brownian motion on $D$ and $h$ is a bounded harmonic function of $X$. It follows that $h$ is smooth on $D$.

By using the Ito's formula and the harmonicity of $h$, we have
\begin{align*}
&e^{- t \wedge \tau_D \wedge \sigma_K }h(X_{t \wedge \tau_D \wedge \sigma_K})-e^{-0}h(X_0) \\
&=-\int_{0}^{t \wedge \tau_D \wedge \sigma_K}e^{-s}h(X_s)\,ds+\int_{0}^{t \wedge \tau_D \wedge \sigma_K} e^{-s}\nabla h(X_s)\,dB_s+\int_{0}^{t \wedge \tau_D \wedge \sigma_K}e^{-s} (\Delta h/2)(X_s)\,ds \\
&=-\int_{0}^{t \wedge \tau_D \wedge \sigma_K}e^{-s}h(X_s)\,ds+\int_{0}^{t \wedge \tau_D \wedge \sigma_K} e^{-s}\nabla h(X_s)\,dB_s+0.
\end{align*}
Taking expectation in $P_x$ and letting $t\to \infty$, we obtain the conclusion. We can apply this arguments to general semimartingales. It is unclear if the identity is true when $X$ is not semimartingale.

Comment: This looks like a good old Dynkin's formula. I assume $h$ is smooth and vanishes on the boundary; the only question is therefore whether the growth of $h$ at infinity is small enough, so that $h$ can be written as the $1$-resolvent applied to $h$: $h(x) = E_x \int_0^\infty e^{-s} h(X_s) ds$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This formula appears in the paper mentioned above and is applied to some special bounded harmonic functions.

Comment: I modified the question. The formula should be as above.

Comment: @MateuszKwaśnicki Thank you for reminding me of Dynkin's formula. I was able to resolve the question.